# PHPUnit use of deprecated function iconv_set_encoding()

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up PHPUnit loader file but after I require nette 5.3. library it throws this message:

> Deprecated: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is
>   deprecated i n
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Webcontrol\app(phpunit)\library\nette\nette.5.3.php on
>   line 12

I don't want to interfere to the library file in order to avoid possible future functionality obstacles. The thing is that I don't know if I can just ignore the message or if it is really important.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of nette?

Comment: No, I have nette version from 2012 which I think should be sufficient, shouldn't it?

Comment: Well, if you have an old version, it uses old functions that -apparently- are deprecated in your version of PHP. In general it's a good idea to update your dependencies regularly. That way you will benefit from updates, improvements and new features, and you won't have to do huge updates if you forcefully need to update from a version of over 3 years old.